Configuring AWS Kinesis Firehose to a specific S3 Folder
I am trying to configure AWS Firehose to write to a specific s3 directory. For this, in the prefix section of Firehose console, I gave "Sample/". Attaching the screenshot.

Even after this, in the S3, its creating the folder structure
S3bucket/Sample/YYYY/MM/dd/file.json.
Is there a way to omit the expressions (eg.YYYY/MM/dd) and let the firehose use only the prefix, like this => S3bucket/Sample/file.json?

One solution is to add lambda function that triggers on S3 events and changes the final file name. In your case removing the date and other stuff and final name like, file.json

Thanks for the answer. No need to change the filename, it can be the default filename which firehose sends. Just for an example, I gave file.json.
